# A QObject is moved to its own thread, but slots are not executing in this thread - what am I doing wrong, or is my understanding wrong?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on a application to run a hardware test jig. I want the test sequences (a sequence of 'steps') to operate in their own thread, separate from the GUI, so that progress can be observed as the test sequence progresses.

To achieve this, I have created a Worker class to perform the test sequences, which I then moved to a newly created thread. The interface class then sends signals (connected as QueuedConnection signals) to the worker slots to request the required operations. There is also the case of the worker signalling itself to automatically execute the next sequence steps.

My expectation was that by moving the worker to a thread it would end up operating in its own exec() thread, separate from the GUI exec() thread.

Unfortunately it does not seem to work. No concurrent threads appear to be operating, as the whole GUI freezes whenever  a 'step' is executing. I am not getting the GUI progress updates that I was expecting.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from TestEngine_Interface import *

#
#   A Worker Class to run the Test Engine in a thread
#
class QTestEngineWorker(QObject, TestEngine):

    # Signal to GUI to emit steps details to a slot to populate the GUI tree
    stepEmitter = pyqtSignal(object)        # Signal with StepInfo
    # Signal to GUI when a step status needs to be updated
    stepStatusUpdated = pyqtSignal(int,object)
    # Signal that a step is executing
    stepExecuting = pyqtSignal(int)

    # Signal to execute a step (used to signal itself)
    stepExecuteAnother = pyqtSignal(bool)

    # Initialise the TestEngine Worker
    def __init__(self):
        super(QTestEngineWorker, self).__init__()
        # Connect this signal back to itself allowing the slot to recall itself (non-recursively)
        self.stepExecuteAnother.connect( lambda continuous: self.stepExecuteNextPending(continuous),
                                         type=Qt.QueuedConnection )

    # Emit step details to the indicated slot
    @pyqtSlot(object)
    def emitSteps(self, slot):
        ...SNIP...
        # Connect to slot
        self.stepEmitter.connect(slot)
        # Use signal to emit the steps
        for idx in range(self.engine_steps):
            #print( "Emitting step ", idx, "  ID", self.stepInfo(idx).identity)
            self.stepEmitter.emit(self.stepInfo(idx))
        # Signal completion
        self.stepEmitter.emit(None)

    # Enable/Disable a step. Only performs a status update if the state changed or if forced
    @pyqtSlot(int, bool, bool)
    def stepEnable(self, stepIndex, stepState, force):
        #print( "Do Step ", stepIndex, "Enabled=", stepState, "...")
        origInfo = super(QTestEngineWorker, self).stepInfo(stepIndex,False)
        super(QTestEngineWorker, self).stepEnable(stepIndex,stepState)
        # determine the status of this step and its parents/children
        if force or (origInfo.enabled!=stepState):
            self.reportStatusChildrenParents(stepIndex)

    @pyqtSlot()
    # Execute the next step
    #   No testing of status is performed
    def stepExecuteNextPending(self,continuous):
        print( "worker.stepExecuteNextPending(",continuous,") started" )
        print( "Current thread ", self.thread() )
        assert(self.engine_ready)
        next_step = self.nextPending(0)
        if next_step<0:
            print( "No Next Step")
            return
        print( "Executing Step", next_step)
        # Report step execution to the GUI
        #print( "worker.stepExecuting.emit(",next_step,") started" )
        self.stepExecuting.emit(next_step)
        #self.thread().yieldCurrentThread()
        #print( "Sleeping ...")
        #self.thread().sleep(2)
        #print( "... Done")
        # Do the Step
        print( "stepDo" )
        self.stepDo(next_step)
        # Report back the status (and parent's status) to GUI
        #print( "worker.reportStatusParents(",next_step,") started" )
        self.reportStatusParents(next_step)
        #self.thread().yieldCurrentThread()
        # If continuous, signal self to execute again
        if continuous:
            print( "worker.stepExecuteAnother.emit(True)" )
            self.stepExecuteAnother.emit(True)

    # Return step details
    #   Returned step status depends on Full/Partial test mode
    def stepInfo(self, stepIndex):
        ...SNIP...

    # Signal step status to the slot
    def reportStatus(self, info):
        self.stepStatusUpdated.emit(info.index,info.status)

    # Report status of a step and its parents (recursive)
    def reportStatusParents(self, index):
        ...SNIP...

    # Report status of a step and its children (recursive)
    def reportStatusChildren(self, index):
        ...SNIP...

    # Report status of a step and its children
    def reportStatusChildrenParents(self, index):
        ...SNIP...

#
#   Test Engine Interface Class
#       Interfaces the Test Engine Worker to the GUI
#       Operates by sending signals to the Worker, which is running in its own thread
#
class QTestEngine(QObject):

    # Signals to the worker
    #   Request steps to be emitted to a slot
    emitStepsSignal = pyqtSignal(object)
    #   Request a step enable/disable (index,enable,force)
    stepEnableSignal = pyqtSignal(int,bool,bool)
    #   Request next step execution (True to continue to test)
    stepExecuteSignal = pyqtSignal(bool)

    # Initialise the TestEngine
    def __init__(self):
        super(QTestEngine, self).__init__()
        # Create a thread
        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        # Create a Test Engine worker
        self.worker = QTestEngineWorker()
        # Start up the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.start()
        # Connect signals (force as Queued connections - however this should happen automatically)
        self.emitStepsSignal.connect( lambda slt: self.worker.emitSteps(slt), 
                                      type=Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.stepEnableSignal.connect( lambda idx,enb,force: self.worker.stepEnable(idx,enb,force),
                                       type=Qt.QueuedConnection )
        self.stepExecuteSignal.connect( lambda continuous:
                                        self.worker.stepExecuteNextPending(continuous), 
                                        type=Qt.QueuedConnection )

    # Emit step details to the indicated slot
    def emitSteps(self, slot):
        # Emit signal to the worker
        self.emitStepsSignal.emit(slot)

    # Enable/Disable a step. Only performs a status update if the state changed or if forced
    def stepEnable(self, stepIndex, stepState, force):
        # Emit signal to the worker
        self.stepEnableSignal.emit(stepIndex, stepState, force)

    # Execute a step
    def stepExecuteNext(self):
        # Emit signal to the worker
        self.stepExecuteSignal.emit(False)

    # Execute steps
    def stepExecuteFromNext(self):
        # Emit signal to the worker
        self.stepExecuteSignal.emit(True)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my understanding of moving a QObject to a different thread, and hence it having its own exec() loop wrong? All the documentation I find suggests to me that it should work.

My fallback plan is to change the signal interface to the worker to use a queue instead. The signal-slot mechanism seems a much more elegant method. Just a shame it doesn't work!

Code is running under Linux on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: Where is the thread's "own exec" you're referring to? If you move a QObject to a separate thread, you need to connect the thread's `started` signal to the actual "worker" function of the QObject subclass (which usually runs a `while` loop and waits for events using a Queue). I cannot test your program (since you didn't provide the code related to `TestEngine`), but from the look of it you're actually running all functions from the main thread, not the new one.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: The  "own exec" is the default run method of a QThread 
[ quote: 
QThread.run (self)
The starting point for the thread. After calling start(), the newly created thread calls this function. The default implementation simply calls exec_().
  ]


The expectation was that by moving the QObject to the thread then any calls to slots of this object would occur via the threads default exec call.

I have now fixed this issue by implementing it using a queue rather than slots, but I'll see if I can build a simplified runnable version for others to run.

Comment: @ClaytonG Every [direct python] call to a QObject subclass instance method is executed in the thread that calls it, no matter if that object is moved to another thread. Normally speaking using a signal connected to a slot in a separate thread *should* execute it in the target thread, but that "depends". As you already found out, using queues usually solves the problem, but I suggest you to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (yours is far too complex and is missing some parts we don't know anything about).